# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate updates the wrong item

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my model I have a thread that contains an array of comments. When I try to update these comments it always updates the wrong one and I cannot figure out why.

```
        Thread.findOneAndUpdate({
          'comments._id': req.params.commentId, 
          'comments.created_by.user_id': user._id
        }, 
        { 
          $set: {
            'comments.$.content': req.body.content,
          }
        }, { new: true }, (err, thread) => {
         if(!err && thread){
            res.status(200).json({success: true})
          }
        })
```

This code works, but it always updates the first comment rather than the one I am trying to update.

Comment: Try `Thread.findAndUpdate({comments:{$elemMatch:{_id:req.params.commentId,            'created_by.user_id': user._id}}}, ....`

Comment: Thanks Veeram, it worked. Do you have an explanation of why this works but what I was trying didn't?

Comment: @AndrewVickerman because, the `dot` notation is not same as `$elemMatch`. `$elemMatch` returns documents satisfying all of the conditions, where as `dot` notation returns documents satisfying any of the condition.